# What is xlsmp in AIX?

Tags: aix, xlc

I have istalled the Xlc compiler for AIX one of the library it installs is: `/usr/lpp/xlsmp.rte/xlsmp.rte/3.1.0.6/liblpp.a`. I am curious to know

What is xlsmp?

What does this library contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**liblpp.a** contains the installp packaging metadata for the fileset. Every AIX fileset (package) contains a liblpp.a with the fileset specific packaging information.

The actual SMP runtime libraries are not shipped in **xlsmp.rte**, they are in the dependent fileset **xlsmp.aix53.rte**, and the paths of those libraries are:

- /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlomp_ser.a
- /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmp.a
- /usr/lpp/xlsmp/aix53/libxlsmpdebug.a

**xlsmp** is the IBM XL compiler's Shared-memory parallelism (SMP) runtime library/environment. Here's some reference pages from the Knowledge Center:

- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlc1313.aix.doc/proguide/qsmp_opts.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlc1313.aix.doc/compiler_ref/ruliblnk.html
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH2K_13.1.3/com.ibm.xlc1313.aix.doc/install/xlsmp_filesets.html